# Implementing Regex into Access VBA for Password Complexity

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I'm currently working on a project that requires password validation, as End Users have the ability to change their login password, but there is no validation to ensure that the given password is within compliance.

It's been a little tricky, as I'm fairly new to working with VBA and Regular Expressions, and I can't quite find the answer I'm looking for.

The project has an Access 2010 Front End, and while I have the line of Regex code that I need to validate the passwords, I'm still a little unsure as to how I can implement it in a function, and call it in my form after the User enters a password.

The code I've been trying to get work is as follows:

```
'Password must be between 7 to 12 characters
'Password must contain at least 1 Lowercase, 1 Uppercase, 1 number, and/or 1 Special character


Public Function fValPass(ByVal strPass As String) As Boolean
Dim result As String
Dim RE As Object
'   Sets the regular expression object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d))|(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{7,12}$"
    '   Does not ignore case
    .IgnoreCase = False
RE.Execute (strPass)

If fValPass = True Then
MsgBox "True", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "False", vbOKOnly
    End If
    End With
End Function
```

I know it might be clunky, but I'm really at a loss here. I'd appreciate any help getting me on the right track, but I realize this might be a rather niche thing I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the answer, Also, the `test` method is the one that return you a yes/no answer. `Execute` returns a set of string that matches

```
Public Function fValPass(ByVal strPass As String) As Boolean
Dim result As String
Dim RE As Object
'   Sets the regular expression object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d))|(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{7,12}$"
    '   Does not ignore case
    .IgnoreCase = False
    fValPass  = .Test(strPass) 'affecting to the name of the function is how you return a value in VBA
end with
End Function
```

P.S. I assumed that the message box was for tests only and removed it

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I got it to call properly in my form, so the big hurdle is done. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

with VB.net it would look something like:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
Dim re As Regex = New Regex("^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d))|(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{7,12}$")
Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
```

With VBA it would look something like this:

```
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W])|(?=.*\W)(?=.*\d))|(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{7,12}$"
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        MsgBox ("matched")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not matched")
    End If
```

The variable MC could be tested, if it contains any values then your source string was matched by your regex.

Comment: The post state that it must be done in VBA. your solution does not work in VBA

Comment: also included a vba example

Comment: What is `strReplace`